# BlueJ connecting a calculator applet to two classes

Tags: java, applet, calculator, bluej

Im running into a most likely easy issue to fix, but I've searched for a long time and I cannot figure out the answer. I'm looking to use the blueJ applet class to make a basic calculator, where it simply takes the string values of different classes and spits them into an interface for me.

My applet looks like this;

```
    import acm.program.*;
    import acm.gui.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.Color;


  public class Calculator extends Program
  {
     private JTextField infix, postfix, result;
     private JLabel infixLabel, postfixLabel, resultLabel;
     private JButton goButton, clearButton;

public Calculator()
{
    start();
    setSize(400, 200);
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

public void init()
{
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(4, 2);
    setLayout(table);

    infix = new JTextField();
    postfix = new JTextField();
    result = new JTextField();

    postfix.setEditable(false);
    result.setEditable(false);

    Dimension d = infix.getPreferredSize();
    d.setSize(200, d.getHeight());
    infix.setPreferredSize(d);

    infixLabel = new JLabel("<html><b>infix</b></html>");
    infixLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    postfixLabel = new JLabel("<html><b>postfix</b></html>");
    postfixLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    resultLabel = new JLabel("result");
    resultLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    goButton = new JButton("Go!");
    goButton.setActionCommand("Go!");
    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setActionCommand("Clear");

    add(infixLabel);
    add(infix);
    add(postfixLabel);
    add(postfix);
    add(resultLabel);
    add(result);
    add(goButton);
    add(clearButton);

    addActionListeners();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String infixString = ""; // Change this line
    String expression = ""; // Change this line   
    String postfixString;

    String what = ae.getActionCommand();
    if (what.equals("Clear"))
    {
        infix.setText("");
        postfix.setText("");
        result.setText("");
    }
    else if (what.equals("Go!"))
    {
        postfixString = ""; //Change this line
        postfix.setText("" + postfixString);
        result.setText("" + expression); // Change this line
    }
 }
}
```

This is for an assignment, and wherever it says  '// change this line' is the part where I have to change. I wasn't here for the initial day my class went over this, and I've searched online for any sort of answer. Basically I have two classes called infixToPostfix that returns a 'string infix' basically putting it in postfix order, and evaluatePostfix that returns a 'string postfix' that calculates a postfix expression.

How would I go about connecting these to my applet?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing all those packages just use the line

```
import java.io.*:
```

Which basically gives access to all packages
Also since you are inheriting a class that class must be in the program as well, this is answer is a bit incomplete but ill edit once i understand the whole thing